# Output of a DATE command in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
DT=`date '+%d %b'`
```

stores "24 Oct" in `$DT`

The command `echo "Date is: " ${DT/ */}` gives 24 as output.

Please help me figure out how 24 comes as the output.

Answer (score 3):

`${DT/ */}` is replacing all the text in `$DT` starting from a space. `*` in glob pattern matches any character.

You can even use:

```
echo "${DT%% *}"
```

to get the same output.

Check for **Parameter Expansion** section in `man bash`.